# Replace PromptDialog with messages upon selection

Tags: c#, botframework

I've trying to replace a PromptDialog with the accepted option along with the a message once the user selects. 
But unfortunately I've been unable to find a solution for it. Because even after the user selects an option, the dialog can be clicked again which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Q. Is it possible ? If so can you please help.

Code

```
PromptDialog.Confirm(context, this.ResumeAfterNone, message);

 private async Task ResumeAfterNone(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> result)
 {
     bool isSure = await result;
     string response = isSure ? "Awesome" : "Sorry";
     IMessageActivity messageActivity = context.MakeMessage();
     messageActivity.Text = response;

     await context.PostAsync(messageActivity);
     context.Done<object>(null);
 }
```

Comment: So you want to "disappear" the dialog after user selection?

Comment: What channel(s) are you using?

Comment: @EzequielJadib - Right, and in place of the dialog for if the original Prompt Question was, "So, were you looking for a bag of tuna?" (yes/no). Once user selects either option what I'm trying to is replace it with BOT- So, were you looking for a bag of tuna? USER-Yes - Does that help?

Comment: @JasonSowers Right now I'm using WebChat but I'm looking forward to using the same BOT code for both Skype & DirectLine, Ty.